# React custom hook returns an empty list on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For a project I have multiple tables that all need a search bar, I've created a custom hook that filters through the table rows.

Here is my code for my custom filtering hook:

```
import React from 'react'
import { matchSorter } from 'match-sorter'

const useFilterData = (searchValue, keyList, data) => {
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState(data)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchValue) {
      const filtered = matchSorter(data, searchValue, {
        keys: keyList,
      })
      setFilteredList(filtered)
    } else {
      setFilteredList(data)
    }
  }, [searchValue])

  return [filteredList]
}

export default useFilterData
```

Here is a snippet from the Table code

```
const data = [{}, {}, {}] // this is a list of objects
const columns = [{'field': 'one'}, {'field': 'two'}, {'field': 'three'}]
const columnKeys = columns.map((c) => c.field)
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('')
const [filteredList] = useFilterData(
    searchValue,
    columnKeys,
    data,
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper>
        <TextField onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} />
        <DataGrid
          rows={filteredList}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When filteredList is first rendered it is always an empty list, once you do a search and then clear the search value the data properly displays. Searching works how I want it to except for whats returned in the first render.
I tried using useEffect like so

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredList(data)
}, [data])
```

but that got me stuck in an infinite loop. I also tried being more explicit in my if statement,

```
if (searchValue !== '')
```

that also didn't change anything!

I am new to hooks, so i'm hoping i'm missing something simple. Thanks.

EDIT: Still been trying things, I've narrowed down the problem I think

```
  console.log(data)
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState(data)
  console.log(filteredList)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredList(data)
  }, [])
  console.log(filteredList)
```

The first console log correctly returns something, the last two always return an empty list.

Comment: I've this exact issue, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredList(data)
}, [])
```